# Output foreach PHP as two column table

Tags: php, html, foreach, woocommerce, tabular

I am trying to get this PHP in Woocommerce to output to a table instead of one big list. I tried HTML table tags, but it only puts the first "foreach" result in the table.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {

// Adds the new tab

$tabs['test_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Amenities', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 20,
    'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
);

return $tabs;

}
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {

// The new tab content

echo '<h2>Amenities</h2>';
echo '<h5>On-Site</h5>';
  $authorvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_onsite');
    echo '<ul>';
  foreach ( $authorvalues as $authorvalue ) {
   echo '<li>'.$authorvalue->name.'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
        }
echo '<h5>Off-Site</h5>';
  $authorvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_offsite');
    echo '<ul>';
  foreach ( $authorvalues as $authorvalue ) {
   echo '<li>'.$authorvalue->name.'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
        }
}
```

The result looks like this right now:

```
<br/>Amenities<br/>
On-Site
<ul><li>Playground</li></ul>
Off-Site
<ul><li>Golf</li>
<li>Hiking</li>
<li>Outdoor pool</li>
<li>Skiing</li>
<li>Spa</li>
<li>Tennis</li></ul>
```

Need it to be in two columns though.

Comment: You need to float your un-ordered lists ( <ul> ) , see how to use [CSS float](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: set your ul's css to `inline-block` or `float left`, like `ul {display: inline-block}` or `#your-ul-container ul{display: inline-block}` or `#your-ul-container ul{float: left}`.

Answer (score 0):

html is a language to describe the semantics of text. 
tables are meant to be used for data that fits in a table.
you really want lists, but in a different format, try some css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .container {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 30px;

        }
        .container ul{
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        }
        .container li{
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        margin: 0;
        }
        .container li:first-child{
        border-top: 0;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Amenities</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>On-Site</h2>
        <ul>
        <li>Playground</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Off-Site</h2>
        <ul>
        <li>Golf</li>
        <li>Hiking</li>
        <li>Outdoor pool</li>
        <li>Skiing</li>
        <li>Spa</li>
        <li>Tennis</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I added a `<style>` for `.container` and wrapped the two lists in a `<div>` important is the `class="container"` attribute which has to match the style. 
there are better ways to include styles, but its a good way to start.